# Molecular orbital diagram for carbene-metal and carbodiphosphorane-metal interaction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, transition-metals, ligand-field-theory

I am interested in understanding how carbenes and carbodiphosphoranes interact differently with a transition metals. I would like to use qualitative molecular orbital theory arguments (with an emphasis on qualitative) in order to highlight key differences.

A carbene is a di-valent carbon, with a long pair (in some structures it may be a diradical). It is a very strong $\sigma$-donor, in addition to being a $\pi$-acceptor: It can form a nice bond with an empty $d_{z^2}$ orbital from a metal, and it can accept two pi electrons into its empty p orbital ($p_x$ or $p_y$ depending on our coordinate system).
The geometry of the carbene, including the lone pair, is trigonal planar.

[image: Carbene]

A carbodiphosphorane, on the other hand, is zero-valent, and has two lone pairs. These may be used in various different bonding schemes (see for example introduction of [this paper](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2019/dt/c9dt00678h#!divAbstract)).
The geometry here, including the lone pairs, is tetrahedral.

[image: Carbodiphosphorane]

Assuming it binds to a metal in the following manner:

[image: Carbodiphosphorane binds to metal]

then I expect that the $d_{z^2}$ orbial is not involved in the bonding, but rather that for example $d_{xz}$ and $d_yz$ interact with the two lone pairs from the carbon.

But I find it difficult to summarize the bonding for a carbene and carbodiphosphorane into (over)simplistic MO diagrams.

Comment: "The geometry here, including the lone pairs, is tetrahedral." - I doubt that. Carbon may well be sp2.

Comment: It is a bit far from my expertise but I thought this papers may be of help: [Stable Carbenes](https://pubs-acs-org.umbral.unirioja.es/doi/10.1021/cr940472u) and [Persistent Triplet Carbenes](https://pubs-acs-org.umbral.unirioja.es/doi/10.1021/cr800518t)

Comment: Links take me to spanish log-in page..